# How to extend one sublist by another sublist if they share a common id at the same index in both sublists?

Tags: python, list, defaultdict

What's the most efficient way of extending one sublist with another sublist if they share a common value at a particular index? I'd like to merge two sublists together if a value at index 0 of List1 is equal to the value of index 0 of List2.

```
List1 = [['aaa','b','c'],['ddd','e','f']]
List2 = [['aaa','1','2'],['ddd','3','4']]
```

Desired Output:

```
[['aaa','b','c','aaa','1','2'],['ddd','e','f','ddd','3','4']]
```

My hack:

```
from collections import defaultdict

Keys2 = map(lambda x: x[0], List2) #returns ['aaa','ddd']
List2_of_Tuples = zip(Keys,List2) #returns [('aaa',['aaa','1','2']),('ddd',['ddd','3','4'])]

Keys1 = map(lambda x: x[0], List1) 
List1_of_Tuples = zip(Keys,List1)

Merged_List_of_Tuples = List1_of_Tuples + List2_of_Tuples
d = defaultdict(list)
for k,v in Merged_List_of_Tuples:
    d[k].append(v)

Desired_Result = map(lambda x: [item for sublist in x[1] for item in sublist],d.items())
```

This returns:

```
[['aaa', 'b', 'c', 'aaa', '1', '2'], ['ddd', 'e', 'f', 'ddd', '3', '4']]
```

I'm doing this to more than two large lists. Is there a shorter more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: What if the input is `list1, list2 = [['aaa','b','c'],['ddd','e','f'], ['eee', 'g', 'h']], [['aaa','1','2'],['ddd','3','4']]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list1,list2 = [['aaa','b','c'],['ddd','e','f']],[['aaa','1','2'],['ddd','3','4']]

from itertools import chain, groupby
from operator import itemgetter
get_first, result = itemgetter(0), []
for key, grp in groupby(sorted(chain(list1, list2), key = get_first), get_first):
    result.append([item for items in grp for item in items])
print result
```

**Output**

```
[['aaa', 'b', 'c', 'aaa', '1', '2'], ['ddd', 'e', 'f', 'ddd', '3', '4']]
```

Comment: I really like this answer, because it uses itertools, which is meant for speed and efficiency. One issue I'm running across with it though is that I'd like to apply it where the index for the match isn't the same in both lists. I can only apply this to when the sublists have the matching strings in the same place (above the matching index was 0), but what if in list 1 the matching index was at 0, as above, but in list 2 the matching index was at 2? (e.g. list1,list2 = [['aaa','b','c'],['ddd','e','f']],[['1','2','aaa'],['3','4','ddd']])). Would this be possible?

Comment: @Chris But that was not part of your original question :(

Comment: You're completely right! You still solved my problem, but a new problem arose, so I was just wondering if I could apply the same methodology. Luckily, I think I can use one of the solutions above for this new issue (although not as fast) and I'm already using yours for the original challenge. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

I would just use list comprehension.

```
List1 = [['aaa','b','c'],['ddd','e','f']]
List2 = [['aaa','1','2'],['ddd','3','4']]

new_list = [a + b for a, b in zip(List1, List2) if a[0] == b[0]]
```

Result:

```
>>> new_list
[['aaa', 'b', 'c', 'aaa', '1', '2'], ['ddd', 'e', 'f', 'ddd', '3', '4']]
```

Comment: You missed the `if they share a common value at a particular index` part.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `List1` doesn't necessarily have a matching item in `List2`?

How about:

```
list2_keys = map(lambda x:x[0],List2)
for i,l in enumerate(List1):
    if l[0] in list2_keys:
        List1[i].extend(List2[list2_keys.index(l[0])])
```

or if you don't want to modify the list in place:

```
list2_keys = map(lambda x:x[0],List2)
new_list = []
for i,l in enumerate(List1):
    if l[0] in list2_keys:
        new_list.append(List1[i]+List2[list2_keys.index(l[0])])
```

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure of the performance of `map` vs list comprehension. You could try generating `list2_keys` via `list2_keys = [l[0] for l in List2]` which may be faster

Answer (score 0):

```
print [List1[0]+List2[0],List1[1]+list2[1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach:

```
List1 = [['aaa','b','c'],['ddd','e','f'],['a','b'],['k','l']]
List2 = [['aaa','1','2'],['ddd','3','4'],['c','d']]
new_list = []

for (index, elem) in enumerate(List1):
    try:
        if elem[0] == List2[index][0]:
            new_list.append(elem+List2[index])
    except IndexError:
        break

print new_list
```